# Why does Vue use it's “in-place patch”, though I'm binding a key in v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to generate a dynamic list of Vue components with a v-for-loop. In that loop I'm passing data which is used by the components and also in some child-components among them.

The items of the list can be deleted individually. So to avoid the “in-place patch” (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) which would mess up the child components I'm binding a key to the for-loop. But it doesn't work.

```html
<div v-for="(shift, index) in shifts"  v-bind:key="index">
  <hr>
    <Shift v-bind:shiftdata="shifts[index]" v-on:DeleteShift="DeleteShift" />
  <hr>
</div>
```

If i'm now deleting a component which is in the middle, the child components of it will be rendered into another component.

Another thing that confuses me is, that if I take "shift" instead of "index" as the key, it works fine. But than I'm getting warnings because the "key is a non-primitive value" and "duplicate keys detected".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because `key`s are identifiers to the items rendered in a for loop. They help preventing the rerendering of **everything** when one element changes.

Now, assume you have the following `shifts` array:

```
shifts = [{a: 10}, {a: 20}, {a: 30}]
```

When you render these with their `index` as the `key`, you're identifying, `{a: 10}` by `0`, `{a: 20}` by `1`, `{a: 30}` by `2` and so on.

When you delete a `shift`, say `{a: 20}`, the `shifts` array becomes:

```
shifts = [{a: 10}, {a: 30}]
```

and the elements are identified as follows:
`{a: 10}` by `0`, `{a: 30}` by `1`.

Earlier, `key: 1` was for `{a: 20}` but now it is for `{a: 30}` which confuses vue.

This is why `index`s are a bad thing to use as `key`s.
`key`s are generally supposed to be unique identifiers for an element, something like database id.

If you have any such entity in your `shift` object, I'd suggest you use that as your `key`

Hope this made sense